# RPC Wallet API methods "getblockhashes" was removed?

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I'm testing RPC wallet API methods of Bitcoin 0.13.2, and I realized the method `getblockhashes` (method returns an array of block hashes for a specified block range ex: between two timestamp) cannot be called, the API returns "Method not found", so is it removed? I'm locking for a method that works like this method.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be mixing something up. Unfortuntately, there are two similarly named pieces of software, `Bitcore` and `Bitcoin Core`, which are different nonetheless.

- `Bitcore` seems to have a method `getBlockHashesByTimestamp` which works as you describe.
- `Bitcoin Core` only has a method `getBlockHash` which takes a blockchain height and returns a single block hash. I [can't find](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getblockhash) a similar method that takes a timestamp for Bitcoin Core.

Comment: `Bitcore` have a method `getBlockHashesByTimesstamp` and this method call `getblockhashes` in client node. I'm using `Insight API` service and the api get blocks `/blocks` doesn't work because `getblockhashes` isn't available. So can you tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: @AnhGien: i think that's a sufficiently large new question to warrant another topic. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, the RPC call `getblockhashes` exists in bitcore patches for bitcoin/zcash etc, because the insight block explorer, which uses bitcore patches for the running node, needs to know last blocks.